# condition_variable, references and threads: Who Owns The Lock?

Tags: c++, c++11, concurrency, condition-variable

Supposing I have a class ThreadQueue holding a `std::queue`, and I pass an instance of it per `std::ref` to a thread. Supposing further, that thread 1 (the main thread) creates and holds the ThreadQueue object and will pour messages into it, and the second thread's task is to take these messages as they come and put them somewhere, say, write them to a logfile.

The class looks like:

```
#include <queue>
#include <mutex>
#include <condition_variable>

using namespace std;

template <typename T>
class ThreadQueue
{
    queue<T> q_;
    mutex mtx;
    unique_lock<mutex> lck;
    condition_variable cv;

public:
    ThreadQueue() { lck = unique_lock<mutex>(mtx); }
    ~ThreadQueue() { if (lck.owns_lock()) lck.unlock(); }

    void enqueue (const T&);
    T dequeue ();
};

template <typename T>
void ThreadQueue<T>::enqueue (const T& t)
{
    lck.lock();
    q_.push(t);
    lck.unlock();
    cv.notify_one();
}

template <typename T>
T ThreadQueue<T>::dequeue ()
{
    cv.wait(lck);
    lck.lock();
    T t = q_.front(); // let's assume that's a copy assignment, because
    q_.pop();         // pop() calls the descructor.
    lck.unlock();
    return t;
}
```

Then in main the tune goes:

```
ThreadQueue<std::pair<int, std::string>> logs;
// and maybe something like:
std::thread logger(std::ref(logs));
```

The crucial line is `cv.wait(lck);` The  documentation clearly states that `lck` is required to be *a unique_lock object whose mutex object is currently locked by this thread.*

The question now is: who does actually lock the mutex, and who owns the lock, thread 1 or thread 2?

Comment: you've created a dealock for anyone who uses this class. the point is to create a `std::unique_lock` as a local variable of a thread-safe function and pass it as a reference to `std::consition_variable. there is no need to keep a unique lock as a member variable.

Answer (score 5):

There are two major mistakes in the code:

1. `unique_lock` shouldn't be a member variable. It must be created on the stack, so that when the scope is left (either upon normal return or an exception) the lock is released automatically for you.
2. `cv.wait` must be called only after you checked that the queue is indeed empty. `std::condition_variable` is a stateless communication mechanism, if signaled when there are no waiters the signal is lost. There are also spurious wakeups. You may like to use `cv.wait([this] { return !q_.empty(); });` that handles the waiting on the condition variable correctly for you.

E.g.:

```
using namespace std;

template <typename T>
class ThreadQueue
{
    queue<T> q_;
    mutex mtx;
    condition_variable cv;

public:
    void enqueue (const T&);
    T dequeue ();
};

template <typename T>
void ThreadQueue<T>::enqueue (const T& t)
{
    {
        lock_guard<mutex> lck(mtx);
        q_.push(t);
    }
    cv.notify_one(); // Optimization: release the lock before signalling.
}

template <typename T>
T ThreadQueue<T>::dequeue ()
{
    unique_lock<mutex> lck(mtx);
    cv.wait(lck, [this] { return !q_.empty(); });
    T t = q_.front();
    q_.pop();
    return t;
}
```

> Who owns the lock?

The thread that has locked the mutex owns the lock, or entered the *critical section*. Both `std::lock_guard` and `std::unique_lock` here lock the mutex in the constructor and unlock in the destructor (upon normal scope exit or exception).

Comment: Ok, thank you very much, @Maxim, for this edit. I'm still getting warm with C++, and you certainly saved me from hours of probably most unpleasant debugging. However, the question remains: if thread 1 passes the queue **per reference** to thread 2, and thread 2 calls dequeue(), that way locking the mutex, who owns the lock?

Comment: @SlabSlob The `unique_lock` or `lock_guard` should not be shared at all. It's the `mutex` that should be shared and it's that which gets owned. When `lock_guard<mutex> lck(mtx);` returns, `lck` owns `mtx` (has it locked).

Comment: @SlabSlob, Re, "...who owns the lock?" The owner of some mutex `m` always is the thread that called `m.lock()`. When you declare a local variable, `unique_lock<mutex> ul(m)`, then the constructor will call `m.lock()`, and the destructor calls `m.unlock()`, so whatever thread enters the scope of that variable must be the owner of the mutex `m` for as long as it is executing in the scope of `ul`.

Comment: Thank you, @all, for clarifying this. I believe I'm beginning to understand. (Maybe Perl is still cluttering up my mind...)