# c++: condition variable ownership

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, condition-variable, thread-synchronization

I am facing an issue while performing thread synchronisation.

I have a class very similar to the `ThreadQueue` implementation proposed in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60156177/3540528), which I'll briefly report here for completeness:

```
#include <mutex>
#include <queue>
#include <condition_variable>

template <typename T>
class ThreadQueue {
  std::queue<T> q_;
  std::mutex mtx;
  std::condition_variable cv;

public:
  void enqueue (const T& t) {
    {
      std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lck(mtx);
      q_.push(t);
    }
    cv.notify_one();
  }

  T dequeue () {
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lck(mtx);
    cv.wait(lck, [this] { return !q_.empty(); });
    T t = q_.front();
    q_.pop();
    return t;
  }
};
```

I have a consumer that continuously extracts the first available item of a shared instance of that class, say `ThreadQueue<int> my_queue;`, until it receives a signal to quit, for instance:

```
std::atomic_bool quit(false);

void worker(){
  std::cout << "[worker] starting..." << std::endl;
  while(!quit.load()) {
      std::cout << "[worker] extract element from the queue" << std::endl;
      auto el = my_queue.dequeue();
       
      std::cout << "[worker] consume extracted element" << std::endl;
      std::cout << el << std::endl;
  }
    
  std::cout << "[worker] exiting" << std::endl;
}
```

Suppose the program has to terminate (for any reason) before any producer can insert elements in the queue; in this case the worker would be stuck on the line `auto el = my_queue.dequeue();` and cannot terminate.
An exemple of this case is the following:

```
int main() {
  std::thread t(worker);
  std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(1));
  
  std::cout << "[main] terminating..." << std::endl;
  quit.store(true);
  t.join();
  std::cout << "[main] terminated!" << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Clearly, the worker can be "unlocked" by pushing a dummy element in the queue, but it does not seem an elegant solution.

I am thus wondering whether the thread syncronisation on the empty queue should be taken out of the `ThreadQueue` class and done inside the worker instead, i.e. moving the "ownership" of the condition variable outside the `ThreadQueue` container.

In general, is a class such as `ThreadQueue` always a bad design?

In case it's not, is there any solution that allows to keep the condition variable encapsulated in `ThreadQueue`, hence removing the responsibility of thread syncronisation from the users of that class (bearing in mind I am limited to usage of C++11)?

Full MWE [here](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e15302c34a8c96e0)

Comment: FWIW you could use `wait_for`  or `wait_until` to add a timeout to the waiting.

Comment: `wait_for` is generally good unless waking thread up every second is going to seriously affect performance of your program (somehow). Otherwise, you need a way to stop `ThreadQueue` from waiting, just like `worker` has. Simple solution: an atomic bool, a `stop()` method that switches the bool and calls `notify_one` and modify lambda in `wait` to check for either queue not empty or bool set.

Comment: @NathanOliver What shoud the `dequeue` function do in case the timeout expires? Throw an exception?

Comment: @Davide That would be a sensible way to exit out after a timeout.

Comment: Can't you change the predicate in `cv` to wait for the queue to be empty or a flag like:  `cv.wait(lck, [this] { return !q_.empty() || !running; });` the flags starts life `running = true;` and when you want to close down your queue (or queues) you set the flag to false. It could be a global/singleton for all queues (not suggesting that!) or anything really... depends where the queue lives

Comment: First you have to decide what should happen when dequeue returns and there is no data to provide. Throw an exception? Return an optional? Something else? Then you can decide how to address this issue. I would change condition in `cv.wait` by adding some `exit` flag.

Comment: @MarekR isn't the whole point of embedding thread synchronisation inside the class to avoid that case? i.e., `dequeue` does not return unless there is data to provide

Comment: @Yksisarvinen I thought about that solution, but it would require to add to the public interface a function that, for instance, would allow anyone to "unlock" the wait  anytime, and I though it is something that should be avoided according to the principle "make interfaces hard to be used incorrectly". Maybe I am overthinking it.

Comment: @Davide you've missed my point. I was asking what are you expecting should happen when `dequeue` is running queue is empty and you wish to stop execution of `dequeue`.

Comment: @Davide It already has a public interface that allows both enqueuing and dequeuing to the same party. That lets producers to consume or consumer to produce. You could split that into two abstract interfaces - for producer and consumer, and only consumer would have access to `stop()` method. Is it a better solution - it depends who you ask. Great practice according to Java programmer, treating colleagues as children according to Python programmer. C++ programmers will just argue with each other.

Comment: @MarekR sorry, now I understood what you meant.

Answer (score 1):

The object that contains the mutex should also own the condition variable. So the `ThreadQueue` code looks good. But it is unclear what `dequeue()` should return when an asynchronous stop is requested.

A common way to solve this is to introduce either a `quit` flag or a sentinel value to the queue itself, a `stop()` method and a way for `dequeue()` to signal a closed queue, for example, using `std::optional<T>` as return value.

```cpp
template <typename T>
class ThreadQueue {
  std::queue<T> q_;
  std::mutex mtx;
  std::condition_variable cv;
  bool quit = false;

public:
  void enqueue (const T& t) {
    {
      std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lck(mtx);
      q_.push(t);
    }
    cv.notify_one();
  }

  std::optional<T> dequeue () {
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lck(mtx);
    cv.wait(lck, [this] { return quit || !q_.empty(); });
    if (quit) {
        return {};
    }
    T t = q_.front();
    q_.pop();
    return t;
  }

  void stop() {
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lck(mtx);
    quit = true;
    cv.notify_all();
  }

};
```

Then when `dequeue()` returns an empty `optional`, the worker can exit gracefully.

```cpp
void worker() {
  std::cout << "[worker] starting..." << std::endl;
  while (true) {
      std::cout << "[worker] extract element from the queue" << std::endl;
      auto el = my_queue.dequeue();
      if (!el) {
        std::cout << "[worker] exiting" << std::endl;
        break;
      }
      std::cout << "[worker] consume extracted element" << std::endl;
      std::cout << *el << std::endl;
  }
    
  std::cout << "[worker] exiting" << std::endl;
}

int main() {
  std::thread t(worker);
  std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(1));
  
  std::cout << "[main] terminating..." << std::endl;
  my_queue.stop();
  t.join();
  std::cout << "[main] terminated!" << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a quick hacky mod to your class to add stop function:

```cpp
template <typename T>
class ThreadQueue {
  std::queue<T> q_;
  std::mutex mtx;
  std::condition_variable cv;
  std::atomic<bool> running = true;

public:
  void enqueue (const T& t) {
    {
      std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lck(mtx);
      q_.push(t);
    }
    cv.notify_one();
  }

  T dequeue () {
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lck(mtx);
    cv.wait(lck, [this] { return !q_.empty() || !running; });
    if (!running){return {};} // tidy-up part 1
    T t = q_.front();
    q_.pop();
    return t;
  }

  bool is_running()
  {
    return running;
  }

  void stop()
  {
    running = false;
    cv.notify_all(); // tidy-up part 2
  }
};
```

see live example: https://godbolt.org/z/bje6Gj7o4

Obviously needs tidying up as you require

Comment: You have a race. If `stop()` is called between `is_running()` and `dequeue()`, `q_.front()` will crash.

Comment: also `stop()` should invoke `cv.notify_all();`.

Comment: @rustyx true, as mentioned this is just a hacky example solution, needs tidying up - but will add the updates with comments

Comment: @MarekR - also true - added with comment